# Split method and split on the ‘.’ character (without the csv extension)

Tags: java, processing

Modify the constructor so that the name field is set to the filename
without the .csv extension. Hint: use the split method and split on
the ‘.’ character.

I used 
filename.split('.');

```
public DataSet(String filename, color dataSetColor){

    name = filename;
    _dataSetColor = dataSetColor;
    _markList = new ArrayList<StudentMarks>();

    linesArray = loadStrings(filename);

    for(String l : linesArray){

        //Split the current line storing the values in csvArray
        csvArray = split(l, ',');
        if(csvArray.length == 3){
            String id = csvArray[0];
            int internalM = Integer.parseInt(csvArray[1]);
            int ExamM = Integer.parseInt(csvArray[2]);

            _markList.add(new StudentMarks(id,internalM,ExamM,_dataSetColor));
        } else {

            println("The length of the csvArray is not equal to 3"); 
        }
    }
}
```

when I ran this, I want the result shows "dataSet", not the "dataSet.csv"

Comment: so split on '.', check that the last element of your array equalsIgnoreCase("csv"); and print all the elements before it concatenated with '.' where needed. If you need to split on ('.'), why do you split on (',') ?

Comment: The split of "," is for the result of the data. Now I just want to change my filename.

Comment: so what is stopping you?

Comment: name = filename; ( name is the name of my file)
the result of my filename is "dataSet.csv"
I just want the filename becomes "dataSet" only

Comment: so? your assignment tells you exactly how to treat it. just implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change one line (use split with escape):

```
name = filename.split("\\.")[0];
```

The problem is dot is a special symbol you need to escape.

One more solution is to use lastIndexOf method and substring:

```
name = fileneme.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Second solution will work for the case when you'll have dots in file name.

Comment: The compiler said Error on "." Consider adding identifier

Comment: @alexey28 if the assignment states they have to use split, using lastIndexOf is not an option. just split, check the  number of elements in the array, use simple string concatenation et voila

Comment: @Zrrr I fix my answer - please check

Comment: @alexey28 your answer is still flawed if there are . 's in the filename

Comment: The second solution gave me a blank page

Comment: i think the first time I tried was wrong because of your "fileNEME" should be filename

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string by '.' using `filename.split("\\.")`

Comment: this should be a comment, rather than an answer. seeing as the OP has already used the split method in the code posted, it's clear the OP knows how to use the split method

Comment: name = filename.split("\\.");  ?

I tried
name = filename;
filename.split("\\.");

Comment: @Zrr do you understand why "name = filename; filename.split("\\."); " makes no sense at all?

Comment: i tried to split my filename from "dataSet.csv" to "dataSet"

Comment: @Zrrr yes, that much I gathered, but your approach makes no sense at all. that's just what I said. In my very first comment, is a description on how to implement this. It's up to you to first try to implement it.